# Partial Fractions with irreducible quadratics in denominator

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I am not sure how to begin this question, as we have not really covered it in class:

$$\int \frac{3}{x^2 + 4x + 40}\, \mathrm dx$$

Correct me if I am wrong, but it doesn't seem that the denominator can be reduced further - how might I go about getting started on this?

Answer (score 5):

> it doesn't seem that the denominator can be reduced further - how might I go about getting started on this?

That's usually the tipoff that you'll have to use an arctangent. Completing the square on the quadratic yields $(x+2)^2+36$; let $u=x+2$, and you should be able to see what to do next...

Comment: AH ok. It has been a while since I have completed the square. Not sure where arctan figures in though...

Comment: $$\int\frac{\mathrm du}{1+u^2}=\arctan\,u+C$$ is the applicable formula.

Comment: Where did the 3 in the numerator go? And what about 36 from the previous completion of the square?

Comment: 1. $\int\frac{c\,\mathrm du}{1+u^2}=c\int\frac{\mathrm du}{1+u^2}$, right? 2. $\int\frac{\mathrm du}{a^2+u^2}$ is handled by letting $u=av$...

Answer (score 4):

$\begin{eqnarray*}\int\frac{3}{x^2 + 4x + 40}\, \mathrm dx
& = & \frac{1}{12}\int\frac{1}{\left (\frac{x+2}{6}\right )^2 + 1}\, \mathrm dx\\
&  & \left (\frac{x+2}{6}=t,\mathrm dx=6\mathrm dt\right )\\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{t^2 + 1}\, \mathrm dt\\
&  & \left (t=\tan{u},\mathrm dt=\sec^2{u}\mathrm du\right )\\
& = & \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sec^2{u}}{\tan^2{u} + 1}\, \mathrm du=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sec^2{u}}{\sec^2{u}}\, \mathrm du=\frac{1}{2}u+\mathrm{Const}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}\arctan{\left ( \frac{x+2}{6} \right)}+\mathrm{Const}
\end{eqnarray*}$

Comment: By this stage, $\int\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$ is usually one of the "standard" known antiderivatives, so the $t=\tan u$ substitution may not be necessary.

Comment: not sure where $(\frac{x+2}{6}\)^2$ comes from. When I completed the square, I got (x+2)^2 + 36

Comment: @Dylan: $\frac{3}{36\times\left \{\left (\frac{x+2}{6}\right )^2 + 1 \right \}}$...

Comment: hmm, i am afraid that still doesn't clarify it for me. forgive me -  i am new to integrals. i will be sure to consult the prof for the next class.