# Integral: Trig Substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

An AP question asks:

> Compute
>   $$\int_0^{1/3}\frac{9}{1+9t^2}\,dt$$

The only way to solve this is through trig substitution, correct? Since this is supposed to be an AB Calculus question, I thought there may be an easier way to solve it?

Comment: The substitution $3t=u$ makes this an elementary integral, with no substitution at all.

Comment: You don't need any trig sub as long as you turn the integrand into a known integral. Put $t=\frac u3$ to see it.

Comment: FYI, trig substitutions have not been needed for AP calculus tests for a long time (over 20 years?).

Comment: As the solution is an $\arctan$, trigonometry seems unavoidable.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, thanks for the info. Do you think this type of question, based on the integral of inverse trigs are likely to show up on typical AP Cal test?

Comment: Yes. This is a straightforward $u$-substitution of $\int \frac{dx}{1+x^2},$ which is a form I'm pretty sure is fair game for the AP-test. However, you'll almost certainly only see something like this in the multiple choice section, not the free response section.

Comment: This is an example of how knowing more than what is minimally tested can help. Although [Partial Fractions with irreducible quadratics in denominator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76834/partial-fractions-with-irreducible-quadratics-in-denominator) is not tested (it used to be, but this topic was omitted a long time ago), if you've worked through this topic then the integral you asked about would be immediately obvious. For more about this topic, try this search: [arctangent + irreducible + quadratic](https://www.google.com/search?q=arctangent%20integral%20irreducible%20quadratic)

Answer (score 4):

The substitution $3t=u$ gives you the integral
$$
\int_0^1\frac{9}{1+u^2}\,\frac{1}{3}\,du
=3\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+u^2}\,du
$$
(note that $u=0$ for $t=0$ and $u=1$ for $t=1/3$).

This integral is elementary, because an antiderivative of $\dfrac{1}{1+u^2}$ is …

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.Why did you choose to set u = 3t? Why did this lead you to changing the upper value on the intergrand from 1/3 to 3?

Comment: @Haim The idea is to get $1+u^2$ in the denominator, because this reminds the arctangent. Then, if $3t=u$, when $t=1/3$ we have $u=3\cdot1/3=1$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize I did that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now. Under what type of substitution would this fall if I want to look up some videos on the topic? This is not regular integration by substitution, is it?

Comment: @Haim Yes, it's regular substitution. With “I didn't realize I did that” are you referring to the downvote?

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize that I erroneously gave you a down vote.  

Until now, I only substituted in a single variable "u" when integrating. Based on what I see here, I assume there is not a problem to also substitute in multiples or fractions of a variable, if it helps calculate the anti-derivative, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33940/discussion-between-haim-and-egreg).

Answer (score 0):

Using differentiation of trig functions

$\int\frac{9}{t^2+9} dt$

=$\int\frac{9}{9(\frac{t^2}{9}+1)} dt$

=$3\int\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{t^2+\frac{1}{9}}$

=$3tan^{-1}(3t)$

Input limits:

=$3tan^{-1}(1)-3tan^{-1}(0)$

=$3(\frac{\pi}{4})-0$

=$\frac{3\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

By decomposition in simple fractions, using complex numbers,

$$\int\frac{9\,dt}{1+9t^2}=\frac92\int\left(\frac{1}{1+i3t}+\frac{1}{1-i3t}\right)dt=\frac9{6i}(\ln(1+i3t)-\ln(1-i3t))=3\arctan(3t).$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest method I guess.

[image]

Comment: Attaching images is intended for things which can't be easily typeset.  Please take a few minutes to read the mathjax tutorial (if necessary) and typeset this answer.